# biber: Skip custom citefield if it is not defined

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, natbib, biber

I am defining my own bibliographic printouts, to be used with biblatex/biber:

```
\usepackage[minnames=20,maxnames=60,backend=biber,
            natbib=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{thisbiblio.bib}
\newcommand{\articleinfo}[1]{
\citename{#1}{author},
``\textit{\citefield{#1}{title}}'',
\citefield{#1}{journaltitle}
\textbf{\citefield{#1}{volume}},
\citefield{#1}{pages}
(\citefield{#1}{year}). \citefield{#1}{note}
}
```

The command above (`\articleinfo{}`) looks for a certain label (argument #1) in a bibtex file (`thisbiblio.bib`) and, when invoked in the document body, it prints a bunch of info from the bibtex entry's fields. I have a custom field called `note`, that I want to use to print custom info, for instance "a preprint of this paper is available from [url]". However, I want this to be optional, i.e., print the `note` field only if it is defined in the bibtex file for this particular entry, otherwise leave it blank. At the moment I get a **note** printout (like that, in bold face). How can I achieve that?

Comment: You should declare a new cite command with `\DeclareCiteCommand` and set field formats appropriately rather than construct things from the `\citefield` macro.

Comment: @DavidPurton This is not meant to be used as the `\cite` command, but to print bibliographic information in line.

Comment: hmmm. Can you provide a full MWE? I think a cite command is still what you want.

Comment: This is for a list of publications, so I'm using, e.g., \item \articleinfo{miguel_paper}. I have a bunch of different definitions, for instance if the paper is on arXiv or a regular journal, etc., each printing the info I want to display.

Comment: Right, but you can use a new cite command to format things like you want and then you can take advantage of punctuation tracker and `\printfield`. A citation command can print anything you want. I'll add an answer and see if it does what you want.

Comment: @DavidPurton Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making new commands with `\newcommand` and `\citefield`, I suggest making a new cite command. Then you can take advantage of `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker and the `\printfield` command, which tests if a field is used.

Depending on your exact requirements, you could minimise the code you repeat for your different sorts of articles with booleans and tests if various fields exist.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[minnames=20,maxnames=60,natbib=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% I'm not sure if your field formats should be global or not.
% I've set the article ones globally to match your question.
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibquote{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\articleinfo}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
   \usebibmacro{articleinfo}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{articleinfo}{%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pages}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printfield{note}}

\begin{document}
\articleinfo{baez/article}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much. They only issue is that I can't use `\mknormrange`, it may be newer than my Livetex installation, so I changed it to `\mkcomprange` instead. Thanks again

Comment: @Miguel, Yes, I think `\mknormrange` is a new command.